# How to enable regmatches to work in dplyr's mutate

Tags: r, regex, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following function, which basically replace the `?` with replacement string `bb_seq`.

```
library(tidyverse)
replace_bb_with_str <- function (seed_pattern = NULL, bb_seq = NULL) {

  sp <- seed_pattern
  gr   <- gregexpr("\\?+", sp)
  csml <- lapply(gr, function(sp) cumsum(attr(sp, "match.length")))
  regmatches(sp, gr) <- lapply(csml, function(sp) substring(bb_seq, c(1, sp[1]), sp))
  sp
  
}
```

It works well with single run:

```
plist <- c(
  "??????????DRHRTRHLAK??????????",
  "????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH",
  "FKDHKHIDVK????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH",
  "FKDHKHIDVK????????????????????"
)

replace_bb_with_str(seed_pattern = plist[1], bb_seq =  "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv")
# [1] "ndqeegillkDRHRTRHLAKkkkkfpssyvv"
```

But when I run it with [dplyr::mutate](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) :

```
expand.grid(seed_pattern = plist, bb_seq =  "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv") %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(nseq = replace_bb_with_str(seed_pattern = seed_pattern, bb_seq = bb_seq))
```

I got this error:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `nseq = replace_bb_with_str(seed_pattern =
  seed_pattern, bb_seq = bb_seq)`.
ℹ The error occurred in row 1.
Caused by error in `nchar()`:
! 'nchar()' requires a character vector
```

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Expand_grid produces factor. thus, convert to character or use `replace_bb_with_str(seed_pattern = as.character(seed_pattern), bb_seq = as.character(bb_seq))) `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`expand.grid()` coerces character vectors to factors, which don’t play nicely with your function. `tidyr::expand_grid()` preserves input types, so your function works fine:

```
library(tidyr)

expand_grid(seed_pattern = plist, bb_seq =  "ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv") %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(nseq = replace_bb_with_str(seed_pattern = seed_pattern, bb_seq = bb_seq))
```

```
# A tibble: 4 × 3
# Rowwise: 
  seed_pattern                             bb_seq               nseq            
  <chr>                                    <chr>                <chr>           
1 ??????????DRHRTRHLAK??????????           ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv ndqeegillkDRHRT…
2 ????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH           ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv ndqeegillkkkkfp…
3 FKDHKHIDVK????????????????????TRCYHIDPHH ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv FKDHKHIDVKndqee…
4 FKDHKHIDVK????????????????????           ndqeegillkkkkfpssyvv FKDHKHIDVKndqee
```

Note that at least with your example data, there’s actually no need to use `expand_grid()` (instead of `data.frame()` or `tibble()`). Or `rowwise()` — you’d get the same output without it.